# Exception when open xls files

Tags: java, excel, exception, apache-poi

I have a xls file which i can open in excel, but when i try to open it with Apache POI, i get this exception :

```
java.io.IOException: block[ 3 ] already removed - does your POIFS have circular or duplicate block references?
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BlockListImpl.remove(BlockListImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.RawDataBlockList.remove(RawDataBlockList.java:34)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BlockAllocationTableReader.fetchBlocks(BlockAllocationTableReader.java:221)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BlockListImpl.fetchBlocks(BlockListImpl.java:123)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.RawDataBlockList.fetchBlocks(RawDataBlockList.java:34)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.processProperties(POIFSFileSystem.java:528)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:327)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:308)
at controlers.ExcelProject2.setBook(ExcelProject2.java:327)
at controlers.ExcelProject2.<init>(ExcelProject2.java:149)
at controlers.ExcelProject2Tests.main(ExcelProject2Tests.java:41)
```

The problem appears at this part of my code :

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(pathFiles);
Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
```

If I open the file in excel, "Save as" and then open the new file with Java, it works. Even if I open the file and save, without changing anything, it works.
I don't know why but the new file is bigger than the old one.

I have tried to use differents solution that i found on google, like using BOMInputStream or NPOI File but it didn't work.
I'm currently using poi-3.8-20120326.

I can not share the file because it contains private information but there nothing else than number and String.

I remain at your disposal for more information.

Regards.

EDIT : I don't know if that makes a difference, but i have forgot to say that the file is in Compatibility mode

Comment: How was the xls generated? Can you post that code? Can you generate one without the private information and share it?

Comment: Well, idk how the xls was generated because he come from a customer. And i can't share without private information because if i change it, the bug disappears :/.
I think i can post a screen if i hide some informations but i don't know if it's useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems that I can see. Firstly, that you're using the older POIFS implementation, which is known to have some issues on certain block combinations, and secondly that you're using [an InputStream when you have a File](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) which has a higher memory footprint

Taking the code

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(pathFiles);
Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
```

On POI 3.12 or newer, the easy fix is to replace that with:

```
Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(pathFiles));
```

That will use a File not a stream, and will use NPOIFS, which is a re-write which fixes issues like the one you have

Comment: is this works for both xls and xlsx ?

if it works, i'll try asap and i'll tell you the result.

Comment: Make sure you write out to a different / new file. In-place write isn't currently supported

Comment: Well, it solved my problem but now i have the following error. 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Position 1024 past the end of the file` 
, when i do : `book.write(fileOut);`.  
I think it's because i don't have InputStream anymore, but what can i do to solve it ?

Comment: This helped me solve a similar problem with the .NET port of POI, NPOI. In my case, instead of calling `WorkbookFactory.Create` with a Stream or a string (filename), I had to create a new instance of `NPOI.POIFS.FileSystem.NPOIFSFileSystem` (using the `FileInfo` overload), and call the factory with it.